# X: alt/ctrl/f1 doesn't work any more after turning the display off and on again with xrandr

Tags: x11, xorg, console, xrandr, virtual-consoles

*(After editing significant new infos into the question)*

After turning a display off from command line (`xrandr --output ... --off`), and then turning it back (`xrandr --output ... --auto`), my X desktop loses the capability to switch to a character console (i.e. alt/ctrl/f1 doesn't work any more).

Other X controlling shortcuts (alt/ctrl/backspace) still work.

Why? How to re-enable this feature?

---

Info: it is Linux Mint, latest stable. The problems happens explicitly after I switched the X off with an `xrandr --output ... --off` from command line, and then turned it on next morning again (with an `xrandr --output ... --auto` command).

I use this, because I need to completely turn it off before I go home and the normal settings (energy settings somewhere in the control panel) aren't enough or buggy.

My keyboard is okay, for example, `xev` shows the alt/ctrl/f3 *release* event correctly:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x2e1, subw 0x0, time 1622285717, (99,77), root:(961,532),
    state 0xc, keycode 69 (keysym 0x1008fe03, XF86Switch_VT_3), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

But the keypress event is *not* in the list. Thus, `xev` *can't see* the press of alt/ctrl/f3, but somehow it can see its release.

---

Debug output:

```
$ xmodmap -pke|grep -i xf86switch
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode  68 = F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2
keycode  69 = F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
keycode  72 = F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
keycode  74 = F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8
keycode  75 = F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
```

The command `xmodmap -pke | grep ' F[0-9]\+'` gives exactly the same result.

---

Additional info: the capability to switch to character console was lost on power off, and not on power on (thus, I had to ssh into my workstation from my mobile to enter the `xrandr --output ... --auto` command).

---

Scripting test: I've tried @GeorgeVasilou 's [script](https://github.com/gevasiliou/PythonTests/blob/master/pykey-test.py), what emulates the keyboard hits by injecting X11 event. The result is negative, the emulated alt/ctrl/f1 sequence appears only as a single `H`.

Comment: Are you sure the first console isn’t where the X server runs? Have you tried <ALT+CTRL+F2>?

Comment: @phg Yes, 1: lsof -p shows its tty, 2: I tried alt/ctrl/f2 and it doesn't work. X have some option for that, but I won't override the default X config of my distribution. [Here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/XServer/) I can read xorg.conf has a DontVTSwitch ServerFlag for this wonderful feature; I suspect my distro enables it by default to make the life of its users nicer. I want to set it back to its normal (false) state, but without the need to override my autogenerated, hardcoded xorg.conf in /usr/share), and without the need of the restart of my running apps.

Comment: It works normally on Mint 18 Cinnamon. What Mint do you have?

Comment: @AlexP Latest mint stable. It also worked by me. After that, I worked a lot, dist-upgraded a lot, and somehow now doesn't work. My keyboard is OK, `xev` shows the keyboard event. I am simply shocked, if I try to imagine what could be going in the mind of the people "inventing" such a change so simply.

Comment: Is there an application / window manager / desktop manager running which may have hijacked Ctrl-Alt-Fn as some sort of hotkeys?

Comment: @AlexP If there are, why they don't hijack them from xev?

Comment: Hm. Could you try `xmodmap -pke | grep XF86Switch`? And `xmodmap -pke | grep ' F[0-9]\+'`?

Comment: @AlexP Thanks, I did. I copied the outputs into my question. I think the serverflags should be mapped to some internal storage, and this should/could be influenced without the interaction in the config files.

Comment: Why don't you copy your autogenerated, hardcoded xorg.conf into a path that's searched earlier (like `/etc/X11`, see `man xorg.conf`), and modify `DontVTSwitch`? It's not like your xorg.conf is going to change frequently ...

Comment: @dirkt Good idea, I am considering to do that. How get I get this autogenerated xorg.conf? I didn't investigated it very deeply, but it seems to me it is coming mainly from predefined constants in the Xorg binary, and actually there is no way to reconstruct it as an ascii configuration file. Or maybe there is some way to dump this?

Comment: If you actually autogenerated a file: It's a normal file, use `less` etc. to look at it. If you didn't autogenerate a file: Just write an xorg.conf with a ServerFlags section, the X server will fill in the rest (internally, without generating a file). If you *want* to autogenerate a file (not necessary and not recommended, but if you need it for some reason), use the `-configure` option (see `man Xorg`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extended comment and not an answer.

In my system, in which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> works correctly, I get a KeyPress event for <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>, but not for <kbd>F1</kbd>. Though I know it works since I'm transfered to tty1.

This is the complete `xev` output in my case (just for comparison):

```
root@debi64:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests# xev -event keyboard
Outer window is 0x4400001, inner window is 0x4400002

KeymapNotify event, serial 18, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967192 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 11550957, (157,186), root:(748,462),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 11550960, (157,186), root:(748,462),
    state 0x8, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 11553775, (157,186), root:(748,462),
    state 0xc, keycode 67 (keysym 0x1008fe01, XF86Switch_VT_1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 11553902, (157,186), root:(748,462),
    state 0xc, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 11553902, (157,186), root:(748,462),
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967169 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ClientMessage event, serial 28, synthetic YES, window 0x4400001,
    message_type 0x11b (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x119 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

I also created a small python script that simulates the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> key press. When I run the script, I'm also transferred in tty1 without problem.

You could even try to run this script in your machine to see if you go or not at tty1, as a double check / verification that your keyboard works ok:

https://github.com/gevasiliou/PythonTests/blob/master/pykey-test.py

PS: Instead of script, you could also try to run `#chvt 1` that should transfer you also to tty1.

After some research it has been reported by other users that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd> keys have stopped working due to xserver updates (obviously), which modified some resolution settings that apply in tty's.

For example [in this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1257791), the problem has been solved by applying a specific vga resolution during boot as a kernel parameter (vga=mode), like vga=0x0362. Obviously one of those system updates messed up resolutions in those guys, so maybe this is also your case (and only god knows why).

PS: To see available supported modes for your system you need to run `hwinfo --framebuffer | grep 'Mode'` and to select a mode from the ones that will be listed.

By the way, you have included some part of xev with <kbd>F3</kbd> in your question, but what is the output with <kbd>F1</kbd>?

**UPDATE:**
As a further troubleshooting it could worth to try some of the following:

1. Looking at [xrandr source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/tree/xrandr.c) it seems that the --off option executes the following commands:

   ```
   set_name_xid (&config_output->mode, None);
   set_name_xid (&config_output->crtc, None);
   config_output->changes |= changes_mode | changes_crtc;
   ```

You could try to reenable the --output by specifying --mode and --crtc xrandr options instead of --auto (just in case that xrandr "automation" is not working correctly).

2. In this [kernel document about console](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/console/console.txt),  you can see what are the drivers / supported modules for operation of virtual consoles under directory  `/sys/class/vtconsole`.
   You could compare values of all the files/modules during power on and after power off that you have a different behavior.
   Maybe something is modifying those values in the -off time.

This is a printout of my system in which switch to tty1-2-3-4-5-6 works ok:

```
root@debi64:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests# for f in $(find /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/ -type f);do echo -e "File : $f \c\c\c";echo -e "-VALUE : \c";cat $f;done
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/bind -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/runtime_active_kids -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/runtime_suspended_time -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/autosuspend_delay_ms -VALUE : cat: /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/runtime_enabled -VALUE : disabled
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/runtime_active_time -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/control -VALUE : auto
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/async -VALUE : disabled
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/runtime_usage -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/power/runtime_status -VALUE : unsupported
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/uevent -VALUE : 
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/name -VALUE : (S) VGA+
root@debi64:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests# for f in $(find /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/ -type f);do echo -e "File : $f \c\c\c";echo -e "-VALUE : \c";cat $f;done
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind -VALUE : 1
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/runtime_active_kids -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/runtime_suspended_time -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/autosuspend_delay_ms -VALUE : cat: /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/runtime_enabled -VALUE : disabled
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/runtime_active_time -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/control -VALUE : auto
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/async -VALUE : disabled
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/runtime_usage -VALUE : 0
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/power/runtime_status -VALUE : unsupported
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/uevent -VALUE : 
File : /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/name -VALUE : (M) frame buffer device
```

3. Finally, could be worthwhile to investigate possible automatic power saving features like Xserver [DPMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling) settings that could be automatically activated in long periods of inactivity.

**Second Update:**

Looking around i found that DPMS and other usefull power save related setting on virtual terminals can be controlled with `setterm` command.
In the case that your virtual terminals seems to be sleeping , you could try to wake them up (if this is the case) by sending a `setterm --reset` command to them. 
To send a command from your regular tty7 to another tty you need to use:
`setsid bash -c 'exec setterm --reset <> /dev/tty1 >&0 2>&1'`
The only problem is that you must be logged in at tty1.

For testing you can use 
`setsid bash -c 'exec setterm --reverse on <> /dev/tty1 >&0 2>&1'` and while your tty1 is working if you switch to it with `chvt 1` you can observe the results (reverse on swaps colors in terminal - tested and working in Debian).

Moreover setterm gives you options to enable/disable powersave using `setterm --powersave off`, and many more (see `man setterm`)

Comment: Thanks! I tried f1, f3, etc, I make the question consistent. I also tried the python code (+ installed the PyKeyboard python module for that). It doesn't switch, it prints only a "H": `$ ./pp
 Lets start - A Key will be typed in terminal now just for testing.
 key tapped
Control Alt F1 will be pressed now
H`

Comment: Strange! In my machine it just switches to tty1. What about if you run chvt 1 or 2 or 3, etc?

Comment: `chvt` is quite funny! As user gives error: `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`. As root: it makes the display black for around 0.2s, then it hangs until ctrl/c. Stracing it shows that it waits in an `ioctl(3, VT_WAITACTIVE, 0x3) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)` syscall. (The EINTR was caused by my ctrl/c.) The relevant strace lines: `ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0 
ioctl(3, KDGKBTYPE, 0x7fff0b6a2767) = 0 
ioctl(3, VT_ACTIVATE, 0x3) = 0 ioctl(3, VT_WAITACTIVE, 0x3) = -1 EINTR`

Comment: Also is this file `cat /etc/default/console-setup` do you have the line ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]" before and after xrandr --off thing?

Comment: Yes, consoles are active, it is in the common linux setting (tty1-tty6 active with a /bin/login from systemd, tty7 has some system log, on tty8 is the X). I can check them with a `cat /dev/vcs[1-6]`, they are ok.

Comment: Note: `lsof -p <Xorg-pid>` doesn't show that it would open any `/dev/fb*` directly. It uses only some `/dev/nvidia*`, `/dev/dri*` and similar. I think this X driver avoids the kernel framebuffer and it deals with the VGA on a more direct way.

Comment: what kernel version do you use?

Comment: 4.8.6, own compilation (but using the mint default with a `make oldconfig`). Can it matter?

Comment: I think no, but in any case i would do a test with a previous kernel version to see if this behavior is kernel related. It has happened before kernel 4.8 to be more "sensitive" in power saving options of various components (i.e rtl wifi cards worked fine in kernel 4.7 but stopped working in 4.8 due to different handling of power saving options).  You could also experiment a little bit with `setterm -powersave off` options or you could enable/disable modesetting to see if it making any difference (also see here : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=168108)

Comment: Last call: If the bug is somehow related to screen resolution of ttys, you could give a try to `#xrandr -s 0` which claims to reset resolution back to normal....

Comment: I am surprised, how could it relate to the screen resolution. I think it is about the keyboard, and not about the screen. I suspect, some setting in the X was changed by the xrandr, and some setting change is happened. The availability of the console switch is configurable in the X config files, maybe it could be configurable also runtime? If yes, I could manually turn it back.

Comment: In terms to bring things back to normal, i updated my answer with some more thoughts. I hope to be useful. If not i have to quit since this goes deeper than what i can handle. If you want, i can also delete my answer to free some space for more experienced users.

Comment: @peterh : Did you found any solution on this problem? Did you make any further tests?

Comment: Yes: meanwhile in the daily work, my desktop hung from around 40 sec. After that, I've found this in the log: `[2401779.536744] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-c8077a5d-3c62-23b7-0c85-72a2d5a56a0f) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[2401779.537022] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-c8077a5d-3c62-23b7-0c85-72a2d5a56a0f) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0`. After that, alt/ctrl/f1 didn't work any more. I think the binaryonly nvidia driver is buggy. But also your help will be very helpful for other people in the future, so here is the +100. :-)

Comment: @peterh Thank you for this reward, though i'm aware that I do not fully deserve it. I hope that this info could help other users to troubleshoot similar problems.

Comment: Don't worry, the original question didn't say anything from this nvidia thing, and your answer is an useful solution for the googlers of the future with a similar problem.